# Incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed, how to fix?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyarrow

At first I got the error `UserWarning: You have an incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed (7.0.0), please install a version that adheres to: 'pyarrow<6.1.0,>=6.0.0; extra == "pandas"'`

Then I followed the advice on [snowflake Python Connection KeyError: 'snowflake-connector-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63953939/snowflake-python-connection-keyerror-snowflake-connector-python) and did the following:

```bash
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyarrow
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall snowflake-connector-python
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall sqlalchemy
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

But then I got the error `UserWarning: You have an incompatible version of 'pyarrow' installed (12.0.0), please install a version that adheres to: 'pyarrow<10.1.0,>=10.0.1; extra == "pandas"'`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way out of this error loop is to install the `pyarrow` version that the error message is asking for.

For example this solved the warning for me:

```bash
pip install pyarrow==10.0.1
```

Comment: Sounds so trivial. Also, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip

Comment: It works in my case

Answer (score 2):

The best fix for this is to install the python snowflake connector with the pandas extra - this then correctly restricts the pyarrow package:

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/d78a8da90775f41ac66b7d22952f5777f8ca2dbb/setup.cfg#L97-L99

In general, use:

```bash
pip install 'snowflake-connector-python[pandas]'
```

So for your example, you'd need to:

```bash
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall \
    pandas \
    pyarrow \
    'snowflake-connector-python[pandas]' \
    sqlalchemy \
    snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

to allow dependency resolution to do its magic.